# Whats the advantage of oop when i cant get user inputs nor create new instance manually?

Tags: python, oop

For example

```
class cats:
    

    def __init__(self, size, height, age, name)
        self.size = size
        self.height = height
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

cat1 = cats(10, 150, 2, "ben")
```

Is it possible to get user inputs in the parameters, and create new instances automatically?

Comment: Is this the same question that you asked a while ago? Can you show an example of a user input that you are thinking about?

Comment: enter cat age: 10 (user)

Comment: and so on etc...

Comment: Ok, I see. Please update your question with the code you have tried for that.

Comment: i havent, cuz i dont know how to get user input in the parameters.

Comment: Ok, have you looked into using `input("prompt")`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Its just that `input` is one way of getting input from the user. Have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) for it?

Comment: Ok, when should i use oop and classes?

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64669969) from @daktoad on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Below code creates 10 instances based on user input.

```
cats = set()

class Cat:
    
    def __init__(self, size, height, age, name):
        self.size = size
        self.height = height
        self.age = age
        self.name = name


for i in range(10):
    print("Create Your Cat")
    size = input(' -- enter size: ')
    height = input(' -- enter size: ')
    age = input(' -- enter age: ')
    name = input(' -- enter name: ')
    cat = Cat(
        size = size,
        height = height,
        age = age,
        name = name,
    )
    print("Cat Created")
    cats.add(cat)
```

Comment: What is set()??

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset. You can also use ```list()``` instead of ```set()``` and just use ```cats.append(cat)``` instead of ```cats.add(cat)```